# three.js randomly flickers in red and brightly lit

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm working with three.js (r67) and I'm having werid color flickering issues.
it looks like every few frames, for a single frame, some of the objects will be painted fully red. if I have a light in my scene, they will flicker randomly either red or very strongly lit.

it looks like its related to the camera position - at positions it will flicker like crazy, and some positions won't flicker at all.

have anyone experienced problems like that and can point me out things to check?

added screenshot below, photoshoped to illustrate how the flickering looks.

thanks!

[image]

Comment: ps. I don't think it's precision problems, my units are 1 unit == meter, and camera planes are 0.1-50. also, materials are either phong or lambert.

Comment: Post at least some part of the code. It seems silly that material properties are dependent of the camera position, it must be something else.

Comment: I wrapped three with some layers so it will be a lot of code to put, that's why I didn't post it and preferred asking if anyone experienced something similar. anyway I think it can be related to the order in which objects are rendered and that's why the camera position might be relevant. as mentioned in my own answer, seems like it only happens when combining phong with lambert materials, so I decided to stop working on this problem and just switch all materials to phong.

Answer (score 0):

OK it looks like a bug in three.js - if I switch all the materials to either phong or lambert the flickering stops. the problem appears only when having both material types.